# How to mock a OWIN Testserver with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, owin, restsharp

I'm using OWIN with WebAPI integration as WebApp. Future plan is to use OWIN self-hosting which is working fine but the OWIN testserver implementation is not working together with RestSharp:

Sample without RestSharp:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/26/unit-testing-owin-applications-using-testserver/

First attempt is to use a mock class derived from RestClient class:
    public class MockRestClient : RestClient
    {
        public TestServer TestServer { get; set; }

```
    public MockRestClient(TestServer testServer)
    {
        TestServer = testServer;
    }

    public override IRestResponse Execute(IRestRequest request)
    {
        // TODO: Currently the test server is only doing GET requests via RestSharp
        var response = TestServer.HttpClient.GetAsync(request.Resource).Result;
        var restResponse = ConvertToRestResponse(request, response);
        return restResponse;
    }

    private static RestResponse ConvertToRestResponse(IRestRequest request, HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
    {
        RestResponse restResponse1 = new RestResponse();
        restResponse1.Content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        restResponse1.ContentEncoding = httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.FirstOrDefault();
        restResponse1.ContentLength = (long)httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
        restResponse1.ContentType = httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
        {
            restResponse1.ErrorException = new HttpRequestException();
            restResponse1.ErrorMessage = httpResponse.Content.ToString();
            restResponse1.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
        }
        restResponse1.RawBytes = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        restResponse1.ResponseUri = httpResponse.Headers.Location;
        restResponse1.Server = "http://localhost";
        restResponse1.StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
        restResponse1.StatusDescription = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        restResponse1.Request = request;
        RestResponse restResponse2 = restResponse1;
        foreach (var httpHeader in httpResponse.Headers)
            restResponse2.Headers.Add(new Parameter()
            {
                Name = httpHeader.Key,
                Value = (object)httpHeader.Value,
                Type = ParameterType.HttpHeader
            });
        //foreach (var httpCookie in httpResponse.Content.)
        //    restResponse2.Cookies.Add(new RestResponseCookie()
        //    {
        //        Comment = httpCookie.Comment,
        //        CommentUri = httpCookie.CommentUri,
        //        Discard = httpCookie.Discard,
        //        Domain = httpCookie.Domain,
        //        Expired = httpCookie.Expired,
        //        Expires = httpCookie.Expires,
        //        HttpOnly = httpCookie.HttpOnly,
        //        Name = httpCookie.Name,
        //        Path = httpCookie.Path,
        //        Port = httpCookie.Port,
        //        Secure = httpCookie.Secure,
        //        TimeStamp = httpCookie.TimeStamp,
        //        Value = httpCookie.Value,
        //        Version = httpCookie.Version
        //    });
        return restResponse2;
    }
```

Unfortunatly I stuck with Post events, which needs html body from restResponse.

Has anybody done something similar.

BTW: I can also use OWIN unit tests with self-hosting OWIN, but this will not work on Teamcity automatic builds.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the mock rest Client to work with Post/Put/Delete methods too. It is not 100% complete (missing auth, Cookies, files etc.), but in my case it is sufficient:

```
public class MockRestClient : RestClient
{
    public TestServer TestServer { get; set; }
    public MockRestClient(TestServer testServer)
    {
        TestServer = testServer;
    }

    public override IRestResponse Execute(IRestRequest request)
    {
        // TODO: Currently the test server is only doing GET requests via RestSharp

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        Parameter body = request.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody);
        HttpContent content;


        if (body != null)
        {
            object val = body.Value;
            byte[] requestBodyBytes;
            string requestBody;


            if (val is byte[])
            {
                requestBodyBytes = (byte[]) val;
                content = new ByteArrayContent(requestBodyBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                requestBody = Convert.ToString(body.Value);
                content = new StringContent(requestBody);
            }
        }
        else 
            content = new StringContent("");

        string urladd = "";

        IEnumerable<string> @params = from p in request.Parameters
            where p.Type == ParameterType.GetOrPost && p.Value != null
            select p.Name + "=" + p.Value;

        if(!@params.IsNullOrEmpty())
            urladd = "?" + String.Join("&", @params);


        IEnumerable<HttpHeader> headers = from p in request.Parameters
                                          where p.Type == ParameterType.HttpHeader
                                          select new HttpHeader
                                          {
                                              Name = p.Name,
                                              Value = Convert.ToString(p.Value)
                                          };

        foreach (HttpHeader header in headers)
        {
            content.Headers.Add(header.Name, header.Value);
        }

        content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";

        switch (request.Method)
        {
            case Method.GET:
                response = TestServer.HttpClient.GetAsync(request.Resource + urladd).Result;
                break;
            case Method.DELETE:
                response = TestServer.HttpClient.DeleteAsync(request.Resource + urladd).Result;
                break;
            case Method.POST:
                response = TestServer.HttpClient.PostAsync(request.Resource + urladd, content).Result;
                break;
            case Method.PUT:
                response = TestServer.HttpClient.PutAsync(request.Resource + urladd, content).Result;
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        var restResponse = ConvertToRestResponse(request, response);
        return restResponse;
    }

    private static RestResponse ConvertToRestResponse(IRestRequest request, HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
    {
        RestResponse restResponse1 = new RestResponse();
        restResponse1.Content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        restResponse1.ContentEncoding = httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.FirstOrDefault();
        restResponse1.ContentLength = (long)httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
        restResponse1.ContentType = httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
        {
            restResponse1.ErrorException = new HttpRequestException();
            restResponse1.ErrorMessage = httpResponse.Content.ToString();
            restResponse1.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
        }
        restResponse1.RawBytes = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        restResponse1.ResponseUri = httpResponse.Headers.Location;
        restResponse1.Server = "http://localhost";
        restResponse1.StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
        restResponse1.StatusDescription = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        restResponse1.Request = request;
        RestResponse restResponse2 = restResponse1;
        foreach (var httpHeader in httpResponse.Headers)
            restResponse2.Headers.Add(new Parameter()
            {
                Name = httpHeader.Key,
                Value = (object)httpHeader.Value,
                Type = ParameterType.HttpHeader
            });
        //foreach (var httpCookie in httpResponse.Content.)
        //    restResponse2.Cookies.Add(new RestResponseCookie()
        //    {
        //        Comment = httpCookie.Comment,
        //        CommentUri = httpCookie.CommentUri,
        //        Discard = httpCookie.Discard,
        //        Domain = httpCookie.Domain,
        //        Expired = httpCookie.Expired,
        //        Expires = httpCookie.Expires,
        //        HttpOnly = httpCookie.HttpOnly,
        //        Name = httpCookie.Name,
        //        Path = httpCookie.Path,
        //        Port = httpCookie.Port,
        //        Secure = httpCookie.Secure,
        //        TimeStamp = httpCookie.TimeStamp,
        //        Value = httpCookie.Value,
        //        Version = httpCookie.Version
        //    });
        return restResponse2;
    }
```